# Micrometer - Common tags for specific metrics

Tags: spring, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to figure out how to set common tags for specific metrics.  NOTE: I'm using the Cloudwatch monitoring system.  Here is what I have:

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
    return new MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>() {

        @Override
        public void customize(MeterRegistry registry) {
            registry.config()
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.gc.pause"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("logback"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("process"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("system.cpu"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.buffer"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.classes")
                .commonTags(Arrays.asList(Tag.of("instanceId", instanceId)));
        }
    };
}
```

I'm thinking of a MeterFilter method similar to `MeterFilter.allow("metric.name").tags("tag1","tag2")`

Micrometer does allow me to set the tags at the creation of the Meter, however that does not help me with the Spring enabled Meters.

It appears the only way to do that is by creating two MeterRegistryCustomizer objects, one for the Spring metrics and any custom metrics I create that DO need the common tags and the other for those that don't.

Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add tags to specific meters, register `MeterFilter` as a bean. For an example, see the following code: https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/so-53925641/src/main/java/com/izeye/sample/config/MetricsConfig.java#L40-L52

Comment: Ugh...it's a bit clunky, but it worked.  I didn't need to create a separate bean, I just instantiated MeterFilter in-line.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity sake, here's my solution with code.  The chosen answer suggested an @Autowired MeterFilter bean, but that wasn't necessary for my specific use-case.

In order to differentiate between meters that I do and do not want to have the instanceId tag, I set an "AGG" tag-key on those that I don't want to have the instanceId tag (i.e. they are metrics that will be aggregated from all instances) and then remove it.

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> buildMeterRegistry() {
    return new MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry>() {

        @Override
        public void customize(MeterRegistry registry) {
            registry.config()
                .meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {

                        // Check for the "AGG" tag
                        if (id.getTag("AGG") != null) {
                            log.debug("Setting an aggregate meter: {} :: {}", id.getName(), id.getTags());
                            // Remove the "AGG" tag
                            List<Tag> tags = id.getTags().stream()
                                .filter(tag -> !StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(tag.getKey(), "AGG"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

                            // Create a new Meter.Id
                            return new Meter.Id(id.getName(), tags, id.getBaseUnit(), id.getDescription(), id.getType());
                        }

                        // Create a new Meter.Id with the instanceId tag
                        return new Meter.Id(id.getName(), Arrays.asList(Tag.of("instanceId", instanceId)), id.getBaseUnit(), id.getDescription(), id.getType());
                    }
                })
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.gc.pause"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("logback"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("process"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("system.cpu"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.buffer"))
                .meterFilter(MeterFilter.denyNameStartsWith("jvm.classes"));
        }
    };
}
```